# Не работает Mirror Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity-mirror

Использую Mirror. В проекте я установил Kcp тип подключения, и если в поле адреса написать локалхост или свой локальный айпи, то все работает, но если подключаться через айпи, то он кидает ошибку:

```
Server Transport Error for connId=1884558144: Timeout: KcpPeer: 
Connection timed out after not receiving any message for 10000ms. 
Disconnecting.. This is fine.)
```

Порт я открыл и проверил через портЧекер. С чем это может быть связано?